# PHP-GD make line height compatible across all fonts on text wrap

Tags: php, gd, image-manipulation, word-wrap

Ok, so am working on a simple generator using jquery. A user enters a text of his/her choice, selects a font, font-color and font-size. All this properties are displayed on a separate div in real-time (live preview).

I now need to save the generated preview as a picture. For that, I use php GD library. All works fine but with some fonts, everything is just messed up.

[image: First font line height looks perfect]

[image: Second font line height messed up]

In the first image, everything looks alright but the second image, the line height is just messed up.

This is my php script that am using to processes the  properties

```
    <?php
        //Width and height of desired image  
        $width = 320;
        $height= 320;

       //Create an image with specified height and width
       $main_img = ImageCreate($width, $height);
       $mx = imagesx($main_img); 
       $my = imagesy($main_img); 

       //Capture values from form
       $main_text = $_POST['rtext'];
       $main_text_size =  $_POST['rfsize'];
       $color = $_POST['rcolor']; 
       $mt_f = $_POST['rfont'];
       $main_text_x = ($mx/2);


       // more code here      


       //wrap text if text too long
       $words = explode(' ', $main_text); 
       $lines = array($words[0]); 
       $currentLine = 0; 
       for($i = 1; $i < count($words); $i++) 
       { 
            $lineSize = imagettfbbox($main_text_size, 0, $mt_f, $lines[$currentLine] . ' ' . $words[$i]); 
            if($lineSize[2] - $lineSize[0] < $mx) 
            { 
                $lines[$currentLine] .= ' ' . $words[$i]; 
            } 
            else 
            { 
                $currentLine++; 
                $lines[$currentLine] = $words[$i]; 
            } 
       } 
       $line_count = 1; 

       // Loop through the lines and place them on the image 
       foreach ($lines as $line) 
       { 
           $line_box = imagettfbbox($main_text_size, 0, $mt_f, "$line"); 
           $line_width = $line_box[0]+$line_box[2]; 
           $line_height = $line_box[1]-$line_box[7]; 
           $line_margin = ($mx-$line_width)/2; 
           $line_y = (($line_height+12) * $line_count); 
           imagettftext($main_img, $main_text_size, 0, $line_margin, $line_y, $main_text_color, $mt_f, $line); 

           // Increment Y so the next line is below the previous line 
           $line_count ++; 
      } 
      header("Content-type: image/png");

      //code to download the image

    ?>
```

Is there a way I can modify the part of the code where I wrap the text to accomodate all fonts? Like automatically calculate the line height based on the font?

Thanks, any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I found a very useful class at phpclasses `imagefittext.class.php` http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/file/41869.html. I also found an example script that is implemented using the class http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/file/41870.html. This is exactly what I wanted.

Worked Perfectly!!!1